# How to Implement Authentication for Expo/React Native Mobile App with OpenSubtitles.com API?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, expo

I’m building a mobile application using Expo and React Native, and I need to integrate authentication with the OpenSubtitles.com REST API. The API requires users to sign in and provide a JWT (JSON Web Token) to my application. Subsequent requests should include an API key (associated with my app) along with the JWT.

I have already tried to get it working by asking users to register through their browsers to Opensubtitles and to provide the application with the username and password, but this feels like bad practice (why would they trust my application with those private details?).

I want to follow best practices and avoid storing user credentials locally (e.g., asking for usernames and passwords and saving them on the device). What is the correct way to implement this authentication flow? Are there any libraries or patterns I should be aware of?

I have found this page which probably is relevant https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/ and provides giudance for OAuth and OpenID providers, but I am not sure if this API uses one of these.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!